# How to solve $8t^3-4t^2-4t+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, cubics

I obtain this cubic equation from solving the trigonometric equation $\sin3x=\sin4x$. I don't know how to solve it to obtain 3 roots.

Thank you!

Comment: The roots of this cubic aren't pretty. $t\sim 0.62349, 0.22252,0.90097$

Comment: Also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Derivation_of_the_roots)

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638874/factor-z7-1-into-linear-and-quadratic-factors-and-prove-that-cos-pi-7-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Added, Saturday: Gauss initiated the study of cyclotomic, umm, numbers, and a simple method for creating polynomials for which they were roots. This is discussed in modern terminology [HERE](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf). The jpeg at the bottom is from an 1875 book by Reuschle, with many, many such calculations.  I put a list of such cubics with prime denominator at   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022216/on-the-trigonometric-roots-of-a-cubic/2022887#2022887  With prime denominator, the cubic is $x^3 + x^2 - \left( \frac{p-1}{3} \right)  x + c$ with an integer $c.$ For denominator $9$ it is $x^3 - 3 x + 1$ instead, page 174 in Reuschle.

ORIGINAL. umm. The roots of
$$ x^3 + x^2 - 2 x - 1 $$
are
$$ 2 \cos \frac{2\pi}{7} \; , \; \;  2 \cos \frac{4\pi}{7} \; , \; \; 2 \cos \frac{6\pi}{7} \; . \; \;  $$
Taking $$ x = -2t $$ gives
$$ -8t^3 + 4 t^2 + 4 t - 1 $$

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> solving the trigonometric equation $\sin3x=\sin4x$

Hint:  use $\,\sin(a)-\sin(b)=2 \sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\,$ with $\,a=4x,b=3x\,$.

Answer (score 1):

When a cubic equation has  are $3$ real roots, one uses a… trigonometric substitution: $\;t=A\cos \theta$, and choose $A>0$ so we can use the formula for $\cos 3\theta$, and I doubt it is very useful in this case.

> Now the trigonometric equation $\;\sin 3x=\sin 4x$ is very simple to
>   solve with elementary tools:

Just remember the basics of  trigonometric equations: 
\begin{align}
\sin x&=\sin\alpha\iff \begin{cases}s\equiv\alpha\mod 2\pi\\[-1ex]\qquad\text{ or }\\[-1ex]x\equiv\pi-\alpha\mod 2\pi\end{cases}\\[1ex]
\cos x&=\cos\alpha\iff x \equiv\pm\alpha\mod 2\pi \\[1ex]
\tan x&=\tan\alpha\iff x \equiv\alpha\mod \pi.
\end{align}

Therefore, the solutions of the  trigonometric equation satisfy
\begin{cases}
4x\equiv 3x\mod 2\pi\iff x\equiv 0\mod 2\pi \\[-1ex]\qquad\text{ or }\\[-1ex]
4x\equiv \pi- 3x\mod 2\pi\iff 7x\equiv\pi\mod 2\pi\iff x\equiv\dfrac\pi7\mod \dfrac{2\pi}7.
\end{cases}

Answer (score 0):

As Will has said, when you make the substitution $x=2t$, then your polynomial instantly becomes
$$P(x)=x^3+x^2-2x-1$$
The roots can be shown to be equal to$$\begin{align*}x_1 & =2\cos\frac {2\pi}7\\ x_2 & =2\cos\frac {4\pi}7\\x_3 & =2\cos\frac {8\pi}7\end{align*}$$
First, make the transformation $x=u+u^{-1}$ and expand to get that
$$\frac {u^6+u^5+u^4+u^3+u^2+u+1}{u^3}=0$$Multiply both sides by $u-1$ and clear the fraction to get$$u^7=1$$
Through DeMoivre’s Theorem, the solution to $u$ is simply$$u=e^{2k\pi i/7}$$where $k=0,1,2,\ldots,6$. Therefore, by the original substitution$$x=e^{2k\pi i/7}+e^{-2k\pi i/7}=2\cos\frac {2k\pi}7$$
Now, make the appropriate substitutions for $k$ and multiply the result by $2$ to get back to $t$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sin3x=\sin4x \implies \begin{cases}3x=4x+2k\pi\implies x=2k\pi\\3x=\pi-4x+2k\pi\implies x=\frac{\pi}7+\frac{2k\pi}7\end{cases}$$