# Given that $\cos\frac{k\pi}{7}$ for $k = 1,3,5$ are the roots of the equation $8x^3-4 x^2 - 4 x + 1=0$, find values of $\sin\frac{k\pi}{14}$

Tags: trigonometry, roots

Given that $\cos\frac{\pi}7, \cos\frac{3\pi}7 \cos\frac{5\pi}7$ are the roots of the equation $8x^3-4 x^2 - 4x + 1=0$ . The value of $\sin\frac{\pi}{14} ;\sin\frac{3\pi}{14} ;\sin\frac{5\pi}{14}$

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N6Lt.jpg). I was trying to solve this problem using theory of equations taking the product of the roots to be $-1$.

Comment: I asked a similar question here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878704/how-to-solve-8t3-4t2-4t1-0/2878712?noredirect=1#comment5942884_2878712 Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac{(2k+1)\pi}7=?$$ $k=0,1,2$

Comment: Thanks sir.can you please tell me from where I can get more questions of this type.

Answer (score 0):

take $w = e^{k \pi i / 14}$ for any of $k = 1,3,5.$ 
Any satisfies $w^{14}+ 1 = 0.$ More precisely, $w \neq i$ and 
$$ w^{12} - w^{10} + w^8 - w^6 + w^4 - w^2 + 1 = 0. $$

Then $2 \sin \frac{k \pi}{14} = \frac{w - \frac{1}{w}}{i} = \frac{w^2 - 1}{i w};$ let us name
$$ x = \frac{w^2 - 1}{i w}. $$
A little fiddling shows
$$ -x^6 + 5  x^4 - 6  x^2 + 1 = \frac{w^{12} - w^{10} + w^8 - w^6 + w^4 - w^2 + 1}{w^6} $$ which is actually $0.$ Our double sines are roots of $x^6 - 5 x^4 + 6 x^2 - 1.$ Taking $x=2s$ tells us that the original sines (as well as their negatives) are roots of
$$ 64s^6 - 80 s^4 + 24 s^2 - 1 $$
[image]