# Roots of $2x^3-4x+1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, roots, substitution, inverse-function, cubics

I'm having difficulty getting the solution to the cubic equation $2x^3-4x+1=0$ and from http://www2.trinity.unimelb.edu.au/~rbroekst/MathX/Cubic%20Formula.pdf it claims that the general solution to $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D=0$ is $$p+q+r=-B/A$$
$$pq+qr+rp=C/A$$
$$pqr=-D/A$$

where $p,q,r$ are the roots.

I also tried http://www2.trinity.unimelb.edu.au/~rbroekst/MathX/Cubic%20Formula.pdf and very carefully followed their technique (which looks at first glance different but must obviously be equivalent) however it didn't line up with what I got from Wolframalpha.  So I'm just looking to see where I messed up or how others would solve this.

Here's my attempt:

$$p+q+r=0$$
$$pq+qr+rp=-2$$
$$pqr=-1/2$$

From the first we get that $$p=-q-r$$
then from the second
$$p(q+r) = -2-qr$$
then from the two of these we get
$$-p^2 = -2-qr$$
equivalently 
$$0=p^3 -2p+1/2$$

Wait!  What?!  A cubic to solve a cubic..... cubics all the way down!?  Obviously not.... so if it's possible to solve this apart from numerical techniques, I would be really interested in such an answer.  Thank you

Comment: Have you tried Cardano's technique?

Comment: Cardano's method. However, this is Casus Irreducibilis, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano%27s_method  but  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis   Finally, the Galois group is not cyclic, so the trigonometric approach is a flop.

Comment: You get the same cubic back (up to a scaling factor). It makes sense: you started with three roots, with nothing to distinguish them. That means $p$ could have been any one of the three roots. If you're just substituting polynomials into polynomials, you're going to get a polynomial back, and to reflect the three possible solutions for $p$, it is going to have to be at least a cubic!

Comment: Will Jagy. Okay.....   I'm familiar with group theory but not really Galois theory (only touched it for a few days), so what do you mean "the Galois group is not cyclic" and how does this imply "the trig method is a flop" and... by "trig method" do you mean the second link I provided?

Comment: Theo Bendit.... sure! I can see that....  but I hate not showing any work.  And honestly this all I have.  I'm not sure how else to proceed, I'm usually good at solving these cubics (and this one has no rational root)

Comment: @Clclstdnt if you wish someone to realize they have a comment from you, begin with an @ sign and their user name.  The trig thing I have in mind is that, for example, one root of $x^3 - 3 x + 1$ is $2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{9}.$ There are other, more complicated examples; the basic requirement is cyclic Galois group. Why are you dealing with the particular cubic you mention?

Comment: @Clclstdnt  left out: if you do the thing with the @ sign, the user sees a little flag, even if no longer looking at this question; clicking on the flag takes one back here

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks! I'm returning to grad school soonish (planning to take the math GRE next month) and came across this while doing an optimization problem.  This is just what I need to solve to get $\nabla f=0$; obviously, I could use a calculator but I want to think more like a (pure) mathematician.  I'm more interested in $any$ techniques I can get that will help me solve this (save numerical b/c I'm interested in pure maths).  So if Galois theory or other sophisticated tools helps and you can point me in the rough direction so that I could investigate it on my own.... Great!

Comment: @Clclstdnt I did the prime denominators up to 1000 at   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022216/on-the-trigonometric-roots-of-a-cubic/2022887#2022887

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}t.$

Thus, $$\frac{32\sqrt2}{3\sqrt3}t^3-\frac{8\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}t+1=0$$ or
$$4t^3-3t+\frac{3\sqrt3}{8\sqrt2}=0.$$
Now, let $t=\cos\theta$.

Hence, $$\cos3\theta=-\frac{3\sqrt3}{8\sqrt2}$$ or
$$\theta=\pm\left(60^{\circ}-\frac{1}{3}\arccos\frac{3\sqrt3}{8\sqrt2}\right)+120^{\circ}k,$$ where $k$ is an integer number.

Id est, we got three following roots:
$$x_1=\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}\cos\left(60^{\circ}-\frac{1}{3}\arccos\frac{3\sqrt3}{8\sqrt2}\right),$$
$$x_2=\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}\cos\left(60^{\circ}+\frac{1}{3}\arccos\frac{3\sqrt3}{8\sqrt2}\right)$$ and
$$x_3=-\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arccos\frac{3\sqrt3}{8\sqrt2}\right).$$

Comment: Nice manipulation ! $\to +1$.

Comment: Could you please include a link to something that has the derivation for these equations for the roots?  Since the link I included has  $\sin$ for the first two roots and $\cos$ for the third.  
+1 for a very clear presentation!

Comment: @Clclstdnt there is a link in Claude's answer. This method mixes trig functions and inverse trig, and does not require abelian Galois group. I don't think I mentioned, for monic cubic with integer coefficients, cyclic Galois group is equivalent to (positive) square discriminant. With your $2 x^3 - 4x+1,$ you may take $x = t/2$ then multiply through by $4$ to get monic integer..

Answer (score 1):

If you use what is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_solution_for_three_real_roots) (since $\Delta=404$ implies three real roots), you should end with
$$x_k=2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{3}-\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}(-\frac{3\sqrt 3}{8 \sqrt 2})\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad k=0,1,2$$

Answer (score 0):

We have a cubic equation $2x^3 - 4x + 1 = 0$, what $x$ is its root ?

May you can solve this by formula $\cos 3t = 4\cos^3 t - 3\cos t$. But I hope that you understood the means and enjoys from apply them on many cubic equations. Indeed, you will solve this cubic equation.

The cubic equation is $x^3 - 2x + \frac{1}{2} = 0$ which have form $t^3 + pt + q = 0$. A cubic equation of this class can be got from $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ if replace the $x$ by $t - \frac{a}{3}$ and then the coefficients $$p = \frac{3b - a^2}{3}\quad \mathrm{and}\quad q = \frac{2a^2 - 9ab + 27c}{27}.$$

Just as $(x + a)^3 = x^3 + 3ax^2 + 3a^2x + a^3$, if $z = e^{it} = x + iy$, then $$z^3 = e^{i3t}=  x^3 + i3yx^2 - 3y^2x - iy^3 = (4\cos^3 t - 3\cos t) + i(-4\sin^3 t + 3\sin t).$$

If $z = e^{it} = x + iy$ and $\zeta = x^3 - iy^3$, then it is $4\zeta - 3\overline{z} - z^3 = 0$. Just as this, if $z = re^{it} = rx + iry$ and $\zeta = r^3x^3 - ir^3y^3$, then $4\zeta^3 - 3r^2\overline{z} - z^3 = 0$.

For your cubic equation $4x^3 - 8x + 2 = 0$, you know 
$$r = \sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}\quad \mathrm{and} \quad t = \frac{1}{3}\arg(-2\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}^3) + \frac{2n\pi}{3} = \frac{1}{3}\arg(-\frac{3}{8}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}})+ \frac{2n\pi}{3}$$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore $$x = \sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}\exp(i(\frac{1}{3}\arg(-\frac{3}{8}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}})+\frac{2n\pi}{3})),\quad n \in \mathbb{Z}.$$
But $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and the term under $\arg$ function is real, so the root $$x = \sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}\cos(\frac{1}{3}\cos^{-1}(-\frac{3}{8}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}})+\frac{2n\pi}{3})),\quad n \in \mathbb{Z}.$$