Solving cubic equations using algebraic methods
I have this equation:
$$x^3 - 3x + 1 = 0$$
I'm trying to solve it, but  I can't figure out how (I would like to avoid using the formula). Is there any substitution or simplified formula I could apply here?

Use Cardano formula

Well, there are no rational roots, so the formula is essentially it - you could essentially re-prove the formula, but the formula is what you get.

You can prove the three roots are real.

The formula for the exact solution is very complicated. In practice , it is usually not used.

Is there any substitution or simplified formula I could apply here? - No.

There is no shortcut here. Your best option is Cardano's Formula. as @SergeiNikolaev suggested

On the other hand, there is a nice expression using methods of Gauss, one of the roots is $2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{9} $   http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf  and a huge compilation  by Reuschle https://archive.org/details/tafelncomplexer00unkngoog/page/173/mode/2up

The roots are between -2 and 2. A method : write $x = 2 \cos t.$   Then $x^3 =  8 \cos^3 t = 6 \cos t +  2 \cos 3t.$ Finally $x^3 - 3x + 1 = 2 \cos 3 t + 1.$   This all works if $ \cos 3t = - \frac{1}{2},$  so that $3t = \frac{2 \pi}{3},    \frac{4 \pi}{3},    \frac{8 \pi}{3} ; , ; ; $   are it.

@Dietrich   this one   has cyclic Galois group  and does work with a trig substitution. It is used in contests, along with $x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1$ for denominator $7,$   from time to time $x^3 + x^2 - 4x + 1$  for denominator $13.$

the responsible thing seems to be linking my answer  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022216/on-the-trigonometric-roots-of-a-cubic/2022887#2022887  and calling attention to Cohen's table, especially the square discriminants  (with an asterisk* )

@WillJagy Very interesting answer there (+1).
